# Migrating user profile picture from D6 to D7

Tags: users, migrations

I'm migrating a site from D6 to D7 and I want to do the User migration in code. The basic profile works fine except for the user picture. I read that it's best to write a separate class for this file so I did. Unfortunately I'm getting nowhere with it.
Can you see anything wrong with this code? I plan to use this class as a dependency in the user profile migration class where I should be able to attach the image based on file id generated in this class.

```
class MigrateDAFiles extends Migration {
    public function __construct(array $arguments) {
        $this->arguments = $arguments;
        parent::__construct($this->arguments);
        $this->description = t('Profile images');
        $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
            array(
                'picture' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'length' => 255,
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                ),
            ),
            MigrateDestinationFile::getKeySchema()
        );
        $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationFile();
        $query = db_select('users', 'u')
            ->fields('u', array('picture'))
            ->isNotNull('picture');
        $query->distinct();
        $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query);

        $this->addFieldMapping('value', 'picture');
        $this->addFieldMapping('source_dir')->defaultValue('http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/artist-pictures/');
        $this->addFieldMapping('file_replace')->defaultValue(FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
        $this->addFieldMapping('status')->defaultValue(1);

        $this->removeFieldMapping('path');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to do picture migration separately per the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/1819706) (assuming you are using [Migrate D2D](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d), which you probably should).  This is all I had for picture migration from one I did last year:

```
$picture_arguments = $common_arguments + array(
  'machine_name' => 'pictures',
  'description' => t('Migration of user pictures from Drupal 6'),
  'default_uid' => 1,
  'source_dir' => '/some/path/to/sites/default/files/',
  'destination_dir' => 'public://pictures',
);

Migration::registerMigration('DrupalPicture6Migration', $picture_arguments['machine_name'], $picture_arguments);
```

Comment: I've seen this example a few times but I do not know where to put it. I have my classes declared in .migrate.inc and then referenced files for each class in .info. The module file is empty.

Comment: @NickO You add it wherever you are registering all of your other migrations.  Most people put them all in a "private" function like `_mymodule_register_migrations()` and then implement `mymodule_flush_caches()` and call it from there.  Then you just need to do a `drush cc all` before your `drush mi`.

Comment: I also had to add some code in prepareRow of users migration class to replace the picture old url with the fid previously imported by the picture migration.